# AWS Python SDK - guarantee that EBS volume and EC instance are in the same availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I am scripting the setup of AWS resources using the Python SDK (boto3). I can create ec2 instances with:

```
ec2_resource.create_instances( .... )
```

and a block storage volume with:

```
ec2_client.create_volume(..., AvailabilityZone = "eu-north-1a")
```

As indicated I can specify the availability zone for the block storage, however I have not understood how to specify that for the ec2 instance; when looking in the console I generally find that the ec2 instance has been created in another availability zone - e.g. "eu-north-1c", and then `instance.attach_volume()` fails because they are not in the same availability zone.

What is the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you're using boto3 and not the outdated boto library ;-)

By specifying the subnet ID to launch the instance into, you implicitly set the availability zone, because each subnet is located in exactly one availability zone.

Comment: Thank you - yes I have seen indications of that in the documentation; but how do I get the subnet ID corresponding to a specific availability zone?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_subnets